# Increase MATLAB precision

Tags: matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

I am studying a paper as "homework" for a class involving numerical analysis. It is required to write a MATLAB code that does the sperimentation the paper studies. Luckily in this paper there are suggested values and the number of iterations required to achieve a precision of $10^{-20}$ (it is about conjugate gradient method and a particular preconditioner, by the way). There are two things that worry me:
First, the number of iterations I need are a bit more than those reported, like 2 or three times more, but that shouldn't be a very big problem. The real issue is that I only have acceptable results for a precision of $10^{-15}$. If I wanted a solution with error bounded in norm by $10^{-20}$, the algorithm can go for even 1000 iterations without going less than $10^{-15}$

Since the numbers on the matrices are obtained by using Euler's gamma function and Beta function, I was wondering if there was a problem of truncation error in matlab. I have found only suggestions about using commands like vpa or digits, but it seems those are referred to a single operation, while I want matlab to be more precise on the whole function. Is there aa way to do this?

Comment: Double precision is around $2^{-52} \approx 10^{-15}$ and I think it is default for matrices in Matlab.

Comment: So the problem is likely the lack of precision in double precision floating point standard.

Comment: Notice that precision is not the same as number of significant digits. The precision in double floating point can go all the way down to $2^{-1022}$, about $10^{-307}$ or so. The problem is that that depends on where your numbers are located. The closer to zero the better the precision that you can achieve. So, if you have some way of shifting or scaling your problem, such that you ensure that your shifted solution is very small, then you can approximate it better. It depends on your particular problem.

Comment: @jyre I hadn't thought about that. The problem is that I have to solve a system like $Ax=b$, so if I want to rescale things, I would do something like dividing both $A$ and $b$ for the same huge number $N$ . That way the solution is the same. The problem is that when I calculate the norm of the residue $Ax-b$, the value I have obtained has to be multiplicated by $N$, so... I like the idea, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: How does the paper (or you) define the “precision?”

Comment: The residual norms of CG approximations generally cannot go below a certain level proportional to the machine precision of the finite precision arithmetic. Of course, making the system matrix and the right hand side 1000000times smaller will make the final residual 1000000times smaller too in the absolute sense, but it won’t change anything about the relative accuracy (or the number of valid digits) of the solution.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel it is simply defined as the norm of $Ax-b$. I will ask the teacher if a lower precision is acceptable, I was just wondering how the author can have achieved that precision

Comment: In CG, you have two residuals: the updated one available freely in the algorithm and the “true” one computed explicitly. The norms of the latter eventually stagnate as indicated in my last comment. However, the norms of the updated one, usually drop much lower than this attainable (even to zero when their components underflow) and thus create a fake feeling of high accuracy you cannot really get. I invite you to make an experiment and plot the norms of both and see this effect for yourself.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel what do you mean? In the algorithm I simply calculate $r=b-Ax$ with $x$ my updated solution, and when the cycle is over I just evaluate norm(r). If it's lower than my rrequested precision, it ends, if it's not it continues until the max number of iterations. Is there another residuum we should care for?

Comment: In the typical CG implementation, the residual is updated as $r_{k+1}=r_k-\alpha_kAp_k$, which has eventually a different behavior than the true residual $b-Ax_k$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Oooooh I see! But I actually need the one I mentioned, it explicitely says that...

Comment: You probably need to use the VPA features then. That might also explain the observed convergence delay. I don’t understand your comment about VPA though. Many functions work for different numerical types and return a compatible result. Hopefully it is true also for the functions you use to assemble the system.